# clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-always-inline' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Tags: c, clang, inline

I want to force the clang compiler to inline the code.
I have already use the `inline __attribute__((always_inline))` while realizing the function:

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void func() {
  // ...
}
```

I tried to compile the code by using:

```
clang sort.c -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -gdwarf-3 -always-inline -lrt -lm -o sort
```

However I got the warning when compiling:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-always-inline' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

And my function is not inlined.
What did I miss?

Comment: A search on [this reference page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) suggestes that there is no such command-line option as `-always-inline` for the clang compiler. (You'll probably get the same message if you add a `-gloop47` option.)

Comment: I also couldn't find it in the clang or gcc documentation. And I think only GCC has the `always_inline` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar I found it here in llvm document.
https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#always-inline-inliner-for-always-inline-functions

Comment: I was looking in the `clang` documentation, not `llvm`.

Comment: Maybe that link is for code analysis options?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks! I tried `-gloop47` option and I got an error saying 'unknown argument'

Comment: regarding:  `int n = strlen(argv[2]);`  function: `strlen()` returns a  `size_t` not a `int`

Comment: regarding: ``-std=gnu99`  the language standard  `gnu99` is 20+ years out of date,, Suggest you use `-std=gny11`